# Async Computed in Components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm finding a solution to async computed method in Components:

Currently, my component is:

```
<div class="msg_content">
   {{messages}}
</div>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    messages: {
      get () {
        return api.get(`/users/${this.value.username}/message/`, {'headers': { 'Authorization': 'JWT ...' }})
        .then(response => response.data)
      }
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Result:
`{}`

How to rewrite it in `Promise` mode? Because I think we can async computed by writing into Promise mode.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Computed properties are basically functions that cache their results so that they don't have to be calculated every time they are needed. They updated automatically **based on the reactive values they use**.

Your computed does not use any reactive items, so there's no point in its being a computed. It returns a Promise now (assuming the usual behavior of `then`).

It's not entirely clear what you want to achieve, but my best guess is that you should create a data item to hold `response.data`, and make your `api.get` call in the [`created` hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created). Something like

```
export default {
  data() {
      return {
        //...
        messages: []
      };
  },
  created() {
    api.get(`/users/${this.value.username}/message/`, {
        'headers': {
          'Authorization': 'JWT ...'
        }
      })
      .then(response => this.messages = response.data);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have data in vuex. Can you help me write your solution code? I'm just learning VueJs and dont get all knowledge youre saying

Comment: See updated answer for example code. I don't know how Vuex figures into your situation, so if this doesn't get you on the right track, ask a new question and be specific about exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfect. No need any package. I voted best for you

Comment: @RoyJ is there a reason to put it in the `created` hook instead of the `mounted` one? Is it faster your way?

Comment: It is earlier in the lifecycle, so it could in theory kick off sooner. As a practical matter, I don't think it makes much difference, @DarkLite1

Comment: Thx for the feedback. I've also read that if you ever plan to go from an SPA to SSR then it's best to not use the `mounted` hook as that doesn't exist in SSR mode.

Answer (score 26):

es7 makes doing this quite trivial by using `async` and `await` in conjunction with axios' returned promise. You'll need the [vue-async-computed](https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed/blob/master/README.md) package.

```
export default {
   asyncComputed: {
       async myResolvedValue() {
          return await api.get(`/users/${this.value.username}/message/`, {'headers': { 'Authorization': 'JWT ...' }})
              .then(response => response.data)
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this package but I heard somebody dismiss this package in here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4083

Comment: @KitKit following the conversation on github, it wasn't dismissed actually, but the vue creator decided not to implement it in the vue core while still stating that the library is good

Comment: How would this be possible without using the async-computed package? I mean, there must be a way with a watcher/vuex ?

Comment: You could use watchEffect with the composition API. It'll only grab the synchronous inputs, but still pretty nice. Something like this:

`watchEffect(async () => { responseRef.value = await api.get(/users/" + props.username" + "/message/,{'headers': ...}).value`

I don't know of an equivalent options api.

Answer (score 2):

I bumped on a similar case where I need to re-run the computed function to fetch from a server every time a data or a props changes.

Without installing any extra package (`vue-async-computed` or `vue3-async-computed` as pointed by other answers), you can force a data to reload by creating a "virtual" computed method.

Lets say you want to fetch data from the server every time the user types their username, and depending on what was typed, you want to show a given message from the server.

From the example below, `username` and `messages` in this case are both reactive data, but there is no direct connection between them, so lets create a computed that depends on `username` by returning its value, which will force it to be called every time `username` is changed. Now you just need to call a function that can be async and will update `messages` after fetching from the server.

In the example below, I use ":dummy" just to force a call to my computed function.

```
<template> 
 <input v-model="username">
 <div class="msg_content" :dummy="force_react">
   {{messages}}
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      messages: "",
      username: "",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    force_react: function() {  
      this.get(); // called every time that this.username updates
      return this.username; // becase its result depends on username
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async get() { // get's called every time that this.username updates
      console.log("Got called");
      let response = await api.get(`/users/${this.username}/message/`, {'headers': { 'Authorization': 'JWT ...' }});
      this.messages = response.data;
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

You can see a working example [here in Vue SFC playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#__DEV__eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHRlbXBsYXRlPiBcbiA8aW5wdXQgdi1tb2RlbD1cInVzZXJuYW1lXCI+XG4gPGRpdiBjbGFzcz1cIm1zZ19jb250ZW50XCIgOmR1bW15PVwiZm9yY2VfcmVhY3RcIj5cbiAgIHt7bWVzc2FnZXN9fVxuPC9kaXY+XG48L3RlbXBsYXRlPlxuXG48c2NyaXB0PlxuZXhwb3J0IGRlZmF1bHQge1xuICBkYXRhOiBmdW5jdGlvbiAoKSB7XG4gICAgcmV0dXJuIHtcbiAgICAgIG1lc3NhZ2VzOiBcIlwiLFxuICAgICAgdXNlcm5hbWU6IFwiXCIsXG4gICAgfTtcbiAgfSxcbiAgY29tcHV0ZWQ6IHtcbiAgICBmb3JjZV9yZWFjdDogZnVuY3Rpb24oKSB7ICAvLyBjYWxsZWQgZXZlcnkgdGltZSB0aGF0IHRoaXMudXNlcm5hbWUgdXBkYXRlcyBiZWNhc2UgaXRzIHJlc3VsdCBkZXBlbmRzIG9uIGl0XG4gICAgICB0aGlzLmdldCgpO1xuICAgICAgcmV0dXJuIHRoaXMudXNlcm5hbWU7XG4gICAgfVxuICB9LFxuICBtZXRob2RzOiB7XG4gICAgYXN5bmMgZ2V0KCkgeyAvLyBnZXQncyBjYWxsZWQgZXZlcnkgdGltZSB0aGF0IHRoaXMudXNlcm5hbWUgdXBkYXRlc1xuICAgICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coXCJHb3QgZ290IGNhbGxlZFwiKTtcbiAgICAgIHRoaXMubWVzc2FnZXMgPSB0aGlzLm1lc3NhZ2VzICsgXCIgY2FsbGVkIFwiO1xuICAgICAgLy9sZXQgcmVzcG9uc2UgPSBhd2FpdCBhcGkuZ2V0KGAvdXNlcnMvJHt0aGlzLnVzZXJuYW1lfS9tZXNzYWdlL2AsIHsnaGVhZGVycyc6IHsgJ0F1dGhvcml6YXRpb24nOiAnSldUIC4uLicgfX0pO1xuICAgICAgLy90aGlzLm1lc3NhZ2VzID0gcmVzcG9uc2UuZGF0YTtcbiAgICB9XG4gIH0sXG59XG48L3NjcmlwdD4iLCJpbXBvcnQtbWFwLmpzb24iOiJ7XG4gIFwiaW1wb3J0c1wiOiB7XG4gICAgXCJ2dWVcIjogXCJodHRwczovL3VucGtnLmNvbS9AdnVlL3J1bnRpbWUtZG9tQDMuMi4zNi9kaXN0L3J1bnRpbWUtZG9tLmVzbS1icm93c2VyLmpzXCIsXG4gICAgXCJ2dWUvc2VydmVyLXJlbmRlcmVyXCI6IFwiaHR0cHM6Ly91bnBrZy5jb20vQHZ1ZS9zZXJ2ZXItcmVuZGVyZXJAMy4yLjM2L2Rpc3Qvc2VydmVyLXJlbmRlcmVyLmVzbS1icm93c2VyLmpzXCJcbiAgfVxufSJ9)

Answer (score 1):

If you ever need a clean computed async, you should use the [Vue-Use](https://vueuse.org/) package (made by the Vue team with tons of useful tools).

More specifically, the computedAsync utility: https://vueuse.org/core/computedAsync/#computedasync

Here's an example from the documentation:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { computedAsync } from '@vueuse/core'

const name = ref('jack')

const userInfo = computedAsync(
  async () => {
    return await mockLookUp(name.value)
  },
  null, // initial state
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a watcher? [Vue Documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#basic-example)

You can use async function in the callback of the watcher.