# Vue computed property returning a promise?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, computed-properties

I have a computed property that triggers an API call and returns the data:

```
async ingredients() {
    const url = "/api/ingredients";

    const request = new Request(url, {
      method: "GET",
      credentials: "same-origin"
    });

    const response = await fetch(request);
    const json = await response.json();
    //debugger;
    return json;
}
```

The debugger I have in there catches when the page is loading and has all the data that I expect to see (variable `json` is an array with my items inside it).

But when I look at the Vue component in the Vue Dev tools, it just says:

`ingredients:Promise`

I use this same structure at work all the time, but I can't figure out what's different about this. If I hit the API route in my browser, I see the expected JSON.

I'm iterating over it like:

`<tr v-for="(ingredient, index) in ingredients" :key="index">`

But as `ingredients` here just refers to a Promise, the table isn't rendered.

I'm not sure it matters but I'm using a Vue/Laravel mix. The Laravel side is working completely fine, the API call comes back in the URL I expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Async Computed in Components - VueJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48641295/async-computed-in-components-vuejs)

Answer (score 3):

The reason here is that computed properties won't actually update after the promise is completed as they operate on setters and getters - so using vuex dispatch here or any other promise will not work.

If you trigger your function on `created()` lifecycle then that should do it. Additionally, if you need to be able to change the recipe dynamically you can set a watcher to catch any updates.

```
data: () => ({
    ingredients: null,
})

watch: {
    ingredients(nexVal, preVal) {
        // do some stuff here
    }
}

created() {
    this.ingredients = myAsyncCallForIngredients()
}
```