# vuejs init data function(methods) in created() or computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was making a simple table and started thinking which one is better or more accurate way to write. I know it's better to use created hook but.. I just want to get ideas what you guys think about it.

We have to display live data (update cycle is 1 sec), but It's very changeable. So I called a initData() function in computed property but my senior used created() hook.

me:
1. methods:  `{ initData() {axios.get().then() }}`
2. call it in computed property(cuz it's updated every sec):

```
getInitData() { this.initData() return this.data}
```

my senior:
1. methods: same
2. call it in created hook(cuz it's init): `created() {this.initData()}`
3. return it in computed property(cuz it's updated every sec):

```
 getInitData() { return this.data}
```

So... What do you think that the performance difference between these 2 cases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Async Computed in Components - VueJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48641295/async-computed-in-components-vuejs)

Comment: wow, thanks for the link but my question is more about 'where to init data which will be updated every sec'. I didn't use call it in created() as your link says computed is for caching. But I kind of get the idea from the link that maybe it's better to set in created() then cache it in computed. hum...

Comment: In that answer basically it says computed properties are not for async data.

Comment: Yeap, I've checked. we use vuex. That example was my bad. Thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make reactive property change in `computed`, it will create an infinite loop

Change `this.data` ---> computed property `recalculated` --> change `this.data`

In `computed`, reactive data get cached and triggers DOM change whenever it gets changed. Now imagine this case when you change a `this.data` once you received API response, as soon as `this.data` gets changes it will trigger computed property, again you will create a network request and again change `this.data` and computed property. It will create an `infinite` loop

Whereas in `created` hook it behaves as a simple method and only triggers when your `component` gets created, which means the first time you will get your data and mutate `this.data`. It will not trigger again at any case until you recreate your component

Comment: ahhh, I didn't think of the loop at all. Thanks! it's very clear

Comment: it's good that you are curious to the solution. Happy to help